# User-action pseudo class with a negating pseudo class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Is it possible to place a negating pseudo class with a user-action pseudo class?

For example:

```
a:hover:not(href) {
  color: blue;
}

// or //

a:not(href):hover {
  color: blue;
}

// or //

a:not(href) {
  &:hover {
    color: blue:
  }
}
```

Here, the hover state of a link would turn the color blue if it did not have a "href".

I am trying to use this with "input[type="radio"]" and change the hover state of the radio if it is not checked (:checked). I know this kind of sounds like an if else statement with CSS, and I guess that's what I am trying to slightly accomplish without having to use js.

Comment: Have you tried it? What happens?

Answer (score 1):

This may not help (always a good start to an answer), but if you control the HTML, then there's definitely a way.  I tried what you'd expect the code to be...

```
input[type="radio"]:not(:checked):hover {
    /* styles */
}
```

...but that didn't work.  It was flickering and rubbish.

So, the only way I could think of was to have a relatively positioned container, and then absolutely position two elements inside it, a `label` and the `input`, and then have the input styles changed when you hover on the label.  Using z-index we can bring the label above the input box.  Then, because of the `for` attribute, we can make sure that the checkbox is still checked when the label is clicked.

The style I've changed on hover is the margin-top, which will pull the radio button up.

**HTML**

```
<span>
    <label for="radio1">Click me</label>
    <input id="radio1" type="radio" />
</span>
<span>
    <label for="radio2">Click me</label>
    <input id="radio2" type="radio" checked />
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
span {
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 13px;
}

label, input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}

label {
    z-index: 2;
    text-indent: -999em;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
}

input {
    z-index: 1;
}

label:hover + input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsbin.com/ifArIn/3/edit